# How do I separate xmlstarlet output with nul?

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet, nul

To I'm trying use nul (U+0) to delimit xml values in xmlstarlet output. `xmlstarlet` ignores `-o ''`, `-o $'\0'`, and `-o '\0'`.

I'm aware that I can use other characters like the various field separators to delimit output. The problem with this approach is that these characters can also exist as data. I don't want any ambiguity.

I want to to use nul specifically because it's the only value that can't be represented in raw XML.

So, to repeat my question: **How do I separate xmlstarlet output with nul?**

#### More information

I've included the following information at the request of the folks who requested it. While I appreciate your desire to help, please avoid suggesting [XY sulutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). I'm only looking for an answer to my question as presented.

The data I'm working with looks like this:

```xml
<data>
    <datapoint attribute-1="val-1" attribute-2="val-a" />
    <datapoint attribute-1="val-2" attribute-2="val-b"  />
    <datapoint attribute-1="val-3">
        <sub-datapoint />
    </datapoint>
</data>
```

The way I'm trying to use xmlstarlet:

```sh
mapfile -tf ARRAY < <( xmlstarlet sel -t -m /data/datapoint -o 'datapoint' -o $'\0' -v ./@attribute-1 -o $'\0' data.xml )
```

A hexdump of the output I'm looking for:

```
64 61 74 61 70 6f 69 6e  74 00 76 61 6c 2d 31 00  |datapoint.val-1.|
64 61 74 61 70 6f 69 6e  74 00 76 61 6c 2d 32 00  |datapoint.val-2.|
64 61 74 61 70 6f 69 6e  74 00 76 61 6c 2d 33 00  |datapoint.val-3.|
```

Comment: What exactly is your expected output given the sample data in the question?

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML and choose a character that is allowed in the XML version you're using.

Comment: @JackFleeting I've updated my question with a hex dump of the output I want.

Comment: @Shawn Unfortunately, that's the exact opposite of what I want. The whole point of using `nul` is that it **can't** be represented in xml. I've updated my question to make this requirement more clear.

Comment: You'll have more luck writing a perl/python/etc. script to parse the xml and print it out as desired, then.

Comment: @Shawn The particular project I'm working with is written in bash, so switching is not an option. I need to have these values separate in bash. Fortunately, I found a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `xmlstarlet` doesn't seem to be capable of producing nul in its output.

`xmlstarlet` is however capable of producing `U+FFFF`; A codepoint that's invalid in all XML versions. You can use this code to safely delimit XML values, and then use another program to replace it with nul:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t \
   -m /data/datapoint \
   -o 'datapoint' \
   -o $'\uffff' \
   -v ./@attribute-1 \
   -o $'\uffff' data.xml \
 | python3 -c 'import sys; 
               sys.stdout.write(sys.stdin.read().replace("\uffff", "\0"))'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$'\1'` which should be just as good as null in majority of situations :

```
mapfile -d $'\1' -t ARRAY < <( xmlstarlet sel -t -m "XPATH" -v "XPATH" -o $'\1' -v 'XPATH' "FILE" )
```

Comment: Only with XML 1.1 though. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML

Comment: @Shawn, thanks for pointing out differences in XML versions. Do you know how to find out XML version supported by xmlstarlet ?

Comment: The one I have (1.6.1) only supports 1.0, though I suspect it depends more on the underlying libxml2 version.

Comment: @Shawn, I have (1.6.1) as well. where did you see it only supports XML 1.0 ? By the way, above `mapfile` command works with (1.6.1).

Comment: Feed it an XML file starting with `<?xml version="1.1"?>`. Look for a warning message.

Comment: This won't work since U+1 can be represented in XML and thus can lead to ambiguity. Also, this question specifically asks for nul in the output.

Comment: xmlstarlet supports only XML 1.0 where U+1 cannot be represented.

Comment: @Philippe A very fair point. i still would like to avoid this approach in case `xmlstarlet` adopts support for XML 1.1 in the future.

Comment: Is it reasonable to expect xmlstarlet to adopt support for XML 1.1 whereas it has not done so for the last 14 years ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation of @TendersMcChiken's answer with perl substituted for python:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m /data/datapoint \
  -o 'datapoint' -o $'\uFFFF' -v ./@attribute-1 -o $'\uFFFF' data.xml \
  | perl -CS -0xFFFF -l0 -pe '' \
  | hexdump -e '16/1 "%-3.2x"' -e '"|" 16/1 "%_p" "|\n"'
```

The output exactly matches the hexdump shown in the question.

**Aside:** since the goal was to capture the result into a bash array, I tried this:

```
mapfile -d $'\uFFFF' -t arr < <(
  xmlstarlet sel -t -m /data/datapoint \
  -o 'datapoint' -o $'\uFFFF' -v ./@attribute-1 -o $'\uFFFF' data.xml
)
```

It didn't work, however, because bash does not support a multibyte character as the delimiter for its `mapfile` builtin. [[discussion](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2021-07/msg00065.html)]

What you could do is have xmlstarlet output 0xFFFF, use perl (or something) to translate 0xFFFF to NUL, and, finally, use mapfile with a NUL delimiter:

```
mapfile -d '' -t arr < <(
  xmlstarlet sel -t -m /data/datapoint \
  -o 'datapoint' -o $'\uFFFF' -v ./@attribute-1 -o $'\uFFFF' data.xml \
  | perl -CS -0xFFFF -l0 -pe ''
)
```